# Access Selfdefined Innerfunction JQueryFunction

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do the following:
2 divs, clickable returning the "value" of the div. This is accomplished by creating a (inner) get_value function on the div.

But wat I really want is to have a button, which reads the value of the div by calling the get_value function.
see code below for example.

Unfortunately i cant get it work....

I have tried to make the values global, but then they are overwritten...

Any clues?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>


        $(document).ready(function () {
            initdiv("a", 10)
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            initdiv("b", 20)
        });

        function initdiv(id, value) {
            function get_value() {
                return value;
            };

            $("#" + id).click(function () {
                alert(get_value());
            });
        }

        function getFoo() {
            var obj = $("#a");
            alert(obj.get_value());
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <div id="a">
        foo
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        bar
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="getFoo();" value="click me and get the value of DIV 'foo'" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not put the value in the DOM and retrieve it on click ?

Answer (score 0):

It's unnecesary the write the function every time you execute the `init_div` function. This function will do the same for you:

```
$('div').click(function() {

    alert($(this).text()); //or '.html()'

});
```

For the button, you can use the same method:

```
$('button').click(function() {

    alert($('div#a').text()); //or '.html()'

});
```

If you want to make it more general, you can use this:

**jQuery**

```
function get_value(selector) {

    alert($(selector).text());

}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('div').click(function () {

        get_value(this);

    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" onclick="get_value('.foo')" value="click me and get the value of DIV 'foo'" />
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yp8V4/

Comment: Your first point, i know, it was just a simplified version of my dot.net code for rendering multiple webcontrols with different settings :)

You are referring to the JQuery function of .Text(), but i want to add some variables to the rendered controls.
Those added variables are these i want to can use/read from other JScript functions.